# How to add registry entries using nLite?

Tags: windows-xp, regedit, nlite

I'm new to nLite. I don't know how to add registry commands using nLite.

I can convert .reg to .inf using Reg2Inf but I don't know how to add this .inf file using nLite.

How can I do that?